# AngularJS - Access promise data throughout application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I have a factory that makes an http get request:

```
grey.factory('JiraData', function( $http ) {
   return {
      async: function( ) {
         return $http.get( 'js/testdata.json' )
            .then( function( result ) {
               return result.data;
            });
      }
   };
});
```

I would like to use the data returned above throughout my application, in various controllers and directives. What is the best way to do this? Can I store and manipulate the data in local/session storage or root scope? If so, what is the best way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are asking a way to call the http.get function only one bug accessing the data more than once, one way is to save the promise on a variable.

```
grey.factory('JiraData', function( $http ) {
   var promise;

   return {
      async: function( ) {
         if(!promise) {
            promise =  $http.get( 'js/testdata.json' )
            .then( function( result ) {
               return result.data;
            });

         }
         return promise;
      }
   };
});
```

And then you can useit like:

```
grey.controller('ACtrl', function( Jiradata ) {
  JiraData.async().then(function(returnData) {
      //your code
  });
}
```

This way, the http request is only call once